# bad operand type for abs(): 'str' in django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates

I am going through the beginning django ecommerce application for shopping cart app. I am getting the error as mentioned above while clicking the add to cart button.

I am getting the error at the line `{{ cart_sutotal|currency}}`

Comment: What's the error that you are getting?

Comment: @Arpit: in the subject of the Q ;)

Answer (score 2):

I remember that book... you're making a custom template filter right? You need to convert the value being passed in to `locale.currency` from a string to an `int`/`decimal`/`float`.

Best practice to avoid rounding errors with currency is to use the `decimal` package.
Import the decimal package and pass your value through the `Decimal` function to fix the issue.

```
    from decimal import Decimal
    value = Decimal(value)
```

So your code should look like this:

```
    from django import template

    import locale
    from decimal import Decimal

    register = template.Library()    
    
    @register.filter(name='currency')    
    def currency(value):    
        try:    
            locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'en_US.UTF-8')    
        except:    
            locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'')    
        value = Decimal(value)    
        loc = locale.localeconv()    
        return locale.currency(value, loc['currency_symbol'], grouping=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#abs).

> **abs()**
>
> *Return the absolute value of a number. The argument may be a plain or long integer or a floating point number. If the argument is a complex number, its magnitude is returned.*

The error raised suggest you are passing a `str` argument to the `abs()` method where as it expects the choice of above mentioned arguments. Solution would be to explicitly pass an `integer` object to the abs method.

#### Example:

```
>>>number = "1"
>>>print abs(int(number))
1
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `currency` filter expects its argument to be a numeric value; you're passing a string to your template as `cart_sutotal`.

Before passing it to the template, convert it to a decimal.Decimal, or, better, figure out why you're adding up price values and coming up with a string for the subtotal.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a cast somewhere in your code. 
Wherever in the code you're doing `abs(somevar)` you need to cast a string to an integer by doing `abs(int(somevar))`. More info if you post a stacktrace or pieces of code.

Answer (score 0):

I think your are writing the code from "beginning Django E-commerce" book.
The error is in your code you write `{{ cart_sutotal|currency }}` in place of `{{ cart_subtotal }}` .

Answer (score 0):

**bad operand type for abs(): 'str'**

I solved this and wanted to share what I found.

**Possible Cause: Decimal Field (or any number field) with "NaN"**

In my case, I ended up with "NaN" trying to come into a Decimal form field, and that made the template processor choke with this exception in *django/utils/numberformat.py*.  I had to figure out where I was saving "NaN" to the database.